# Creating simple c# web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have created a web site definition in IIS and when I create a new web form in Visual Studio it keeps creating it as a .vb instead of a .cs code behind.  I did not create it from any templates, I just want a very simple site with a couple little pages but I would prefer to do it in c#.  Is there something in the web.config (which is also minimal) that would tall Visual Studio that this is a C# site?  This is all done via FTP/Remote.

Comment: Looks like you picked a Project Template that is based on VB. I think the best way to change to C# is by creating a *new project*, using a C#-based Project Template. I would not recommend trying to change your existing project by messing with it (I've been using this for almost a decade and wouldn't know *if* that's even possible or *how*).

Comment: `File > New Project > Installed > Visual C#`. That is where the correct templates are.

Comment: I did not use any templates (per the description above).  I want to set it to c# somehow after the fact.  How would I do this?

Comment: click > Add new element> in the left column > Visual C# > Web > Page/WebForm/MasterPage etc -- I gave up. Creating a project is max 15sec. The longer part is naming it.